# Why amp-ad not loading ads on the pages where content is not in english?

Tags: adsense, amp-html, google-dfp, accelerated-mobile-page

We have a bi-lingual website with amp implemented for the mobile site.
We are using amp-ad tag with type="doubleclick", the ads are rendering fine on english version of website where as for other language its showing empty slot.

Here is the code:

```
<amp-ad width="336" height="280" type="doubleclick"data-slot="/75242261/apherald-mobile-336x280">
<div placeholder></div>
</amp-ad>
```

Also the screenshots for the how it looks.
[image: Add on english page]

Ad on telugu page:
[image]

Comment: Could you also post the link to the page?

Comment: Did you check if you are using one of the [supported ad networks](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad)?

Comment: We are using DFP @noogui, it is supported ad network and ads are coming fine on english version of page.

Comment: http://mobile.apherald.com/Movies/ViewArticle/256492/chiru-mek-show/ here is url for page, browse it on mobile or emulator @kul3r4

Comment: Ad loaded for me, https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtehi6c57vplxfi/ad.png?dl=0

Comment: It's still not loading for me :( @kul3r4